# Exe is running fine when run with VisualStudio2008 (Release Build) but if I run from Folder directly It crash at only one button

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, dll, vtk

I am using QT,ITK,VTK and build theses libraries in X64.

I am developing an application in X64 using VisualStudio2008 .

This application loading the Image data and also provide around 10 buttons for different functionality when I  am running it into debug/Release mode from Visual Studio it works fine, But If I run it from Folder or after making setup by clicking on exe it run fine with all the the features except one that is crashing in mid of the process and it is very random crash .
sometime it crash, sometimes not with the same data and if crash then also not in specific location sometime at

1. `VTKImageData->DeepCopy(data),`
2. `ITKConnectorType::Pointer ItkConnector= ITKConnectorType::New();`
3. `after displaying QT widget on mainwindow.`

But all the other widget functionality are working fine.

Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The random crashing sounds like you are mixing debug and release in the same application. Remember that you can not safely use debug dlls in a release application or release dlls in a debug application. A second option is in your path are dlls compiled from a different version of Visual Studio. Both cases the problem is more than 1 heap caused by using more than 1 crt implementation.

Comment: There is no way you are mixing 32 and 64 bit in the same application. Windows will not load the wrong dlls.

Comment: Hie ,I have modify my question there is no issue with X64 dll. I have checked on my colleagues system it is properly taking X64 dlls. Sometime with the same data it works and sometimes not, I am using Visualstudio  for making set. There is any way to track this issue.

Comment: I also suggest to make extra sure you are using the correct debug/release dll (vtk dlls have the same names in the 2 versions). You can also use dependencywalker for checking your dependencies. You can also try to attach the debugger when you are running the program from the folder (visual studio - debug- attach to process). Of course if you are running a release version you will see very little